# AWS Athena How to check for numeric value before multiplying the value

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, presto, trino

In Athena, we have column which is a varchar column (don't know why it's a varchar column when it should be a numeric column) that we need to multiply its values by 3.

All the values of the column are numeric, except for 1 row that mistakenly has non numeric value.

How can I multiply the column value by 3 only for those rows whose value is numeric ? Or how how I check if the row value is numeric before multiplying it by 3 ?

```
select cast(myColumn as decimal(11,2))*3 from myDatabase.myTable -> this will throw an error on the non numeric value "Cannot cast VARCHAR '5/1/2020 AU' to DECIMAL(11, 2). Value is not a number."
```

Something like this in SQL Server where it will return 0 if it encounters an error will do, but how can I do it in Athena ?

```
select coalesce(try_parse(myColumn as decimal(11,2) using 'en-GB'),'0')*3 from myDatabase.myTable
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`try_cast`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html#try_cast):

> `try_cast(value AS type)` → `type`
> Like `cast()`, but returns `null` if the cast fails.

For example:

```sql
select try_cast(myColumn as decimal(11,2)) * 3 
from myDatabase.myTable
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. try_cast works !